# MySQL database not being updated

Tags: php, mysql, passwords

(Please ignore the fact that md5 isn't the most secure, mysql_* functions are out of date etc. - this isn't going live on any website!)

So, I currently have a system where a user can go to a recover password page and enter their email. It sends them an email with a link to recover their password. This link is as follows:

http://www.example.com/recover_password.php?username=(USERNAME HERE)&recover_password=(CODE HERE).

The code is randomly generated when they register and is being stored fine in the database. However, I am having problems trying to enable them to change it from the above link. This is the recover_password.php page:

```
<?php
include 'core/init.php';

$username = (isset($_GET['username']));
$password_recovery = (isset($_GET['password_recovery']));

if (isset($_GET['success']) && empty($_GET['success'])) {
    echo 'Your password has been changed. You may now proceed to log in.';
    die();
} else {

if (password_recovery_exists($password_recovery) === true && (user_exists($username) === true)) {
    if (empty($_POST) === false) {
        $required_fields = array('password', 'password_again');
        foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
            if (empty($value) && in_array($key, $required_fields) === true) {
                $errors[] = 'You missed a field!';
                break 1;
            }
        }
            if (trim($_POST['password']) !== trim($_POST['password_again'])) {
                $errors[] = 'Your new passwords do not match';
            } else if (strlen($_POST['password']) < 6) {
                $errors[] = 'Your password must be at least 6 characters long.';
            }
        }
        if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true) {
            password_recovery($username, $_POST['password']);
            header('Location: recover_password.php?success');
        }   else {
                echo output_errors($errors);
        }
    }
?>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>Liste - Login</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">          
        <label for="password"><b><center>New Password:</label><br >
        <input type="password" name="password" size="30"><br />

        <label for="password_again"><b><center>Re-enter New Password:</label><br >
        <input type="password" name="password_again" size="30"><br />

        <input type="submit" value="Change Password"><br /><br />
</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>

<?php
}
?>
```

First of all, the major problem is that when they click 'change password' no error messages are displayed, but the password is not updated in the database, leading me to believe that there is a problem with the password_recovery function:

```
function password_recovery($username, $password) {
    $username = sanitize($username);
    $password = md5($password);

    mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `password` = '$password' WHERE `username` = '$username'");
```

I'm not sure if there is a problem with the function or whether the variables are actually being sent or what, so help would be appreciated :)

I was also wondering what the syntax would be to check that the 'username' and 'password_recovery' (from the link) are from the same row in the database?

I understand this code is a mess, outdated etc etc., but help is greatly appreciated :)

Thanks guys!

Comment: The minimum debugging homework you should do is checking the return value of `mysql_query()` calls and `var_dump()`ing selected stuff like function parameters or generated SQL code. Also, `sanitize()` makes a crucial task but we don't know how.

Comment: `$username = (isset($_GET['username'])); ` will always return true or false, not the username, same for $password. And please use PDO or mysqli prepared statements instead of the mysql_* methods.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<?php
include 'core/init.php';

function password_recovery($username, $password) {
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string(sanitize($username));
    $password = md5($password);

    mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `password` = '" . $password . "' WHERE `username` = '" . $username . "'");
}

$username = (isset($_SESSION['username']) ? $_SESSION['username'] : false);
$password_recovery = (isset($_POST['password_recovery']) ? $_POST['password_recovery'] : false);

if (isset($_GET['success']) && empty($_GET['success'])) {
    echo 'Your password has been changed. You may now proceed to log in.';
    die();
} else {

    if (password_recovery_exists($password_recovery) === true && (user_exists($username) === true)) {
        if (empty($_POST) === false) {
            $required_fields = array('password', 'password_again');
            foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
                if (empty($value) && in_array($key, $required_fields) === true) {
                    $errors[] = 'You missed a field!';
                    break 1;
                }
            }
            if (trim($_POST['password']) !== trim($_POST['password_again'])) {
                $errors[] = 'Your new passwords do not match';
            } else if (strlen($_POST['password']) < 6) {
                $errors[] = 'Your password must be at least 6 characters long.';
            }
        }
        if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true) {
            password_recovery($username, $_POST['password']);
            header('Location: recover_password.php?success');
        } else {
            echo output_errors($errors);
        }
    } else {
        die("User not found");
    }
}
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
        <title>Liste - Login</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">          
            <label for="password"><b><center>New Password:</label><br >
                        <input type="password" name="password" size="30"><br />

                        <label for="password_again"><b><center>Re-enter New Password:</label><br >
                                    <input type="password" name="password_again" size="30"><br />

                                    <input type="submit" value="Change Password"><br /><br />
                                    </form>
                                </center>
                                </body>
                                </html>
```

Comment: This code always returns 'User not found' even when the user exists. Is the $username variable being taken from the address bar? I'm new to PHP, not sure what the difference between $_GET and $_POST are.

Comment: Which brings me on to the second question I had - I was looking to find a way to verify that both $username and $password_recovery are in the same row in the database - that way you'd need their (randomly generated and not displayed anywhere) $password_recovery code to change the password. Thanks though - it works!

Answer (score -1):

Try something like that:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `password` = '".$password."' WHERE `username` = '".$username."'");
```